# How to identify if Chrome is showing the security icon

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ckeditor, browser-security

I have some problems in my app with browser security stuff.

Initially, it was not a concern, because all my javacript codes worked fine. But since I've started to use [ckEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) it became a problem, because my ckEditor only work if I enable the unsafe scripts("Load unsafe script"). It's happening only on **Chrome**.

I found out this useful link [Content Security Policy](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html) and I am trying to work around it.

However, I would like to know if there is any way to detect by javascript if the app is being blocked by the browser. Actually I am not talking about the tag `<noscript></noscript>`, because the rest of my javascript codes on my app still working fine. **It's about this particular Chrome's security.**

While I am working on this issue following the Content Security Policy's instructions. Maybe I could identify if Chrome is showing this security icon and give some instructions to the users.

Is it possible?

[image: security block]

Comment: In the official specs there's a [`securitypolicyviolation`](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/content-security-policy/raw-file/tip/csp-specification.dev.html#dfn-fire-a-violation-event) event that should be fired. Did you try to listen for it?

Comment: You shouldn't ask your users to change their security settings, instead you should fix your page so that the security icon isn't shown at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may assume that your website is protected with SSL (HTTPS), while you are referencing scripts from *another* sources than your domain, like the CKEditor tool.

What if you download the CKEditor script file to your server and change the script reference to your domain address?

In addition, take a look at this open issue:
[CKEditor does not load in Chrome when included in a https site](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPCKEDITOR-31?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel) , which if understand currectly, means that you should refer to the CKEditor with `HTTPS` instead of `HTTP` if you are at a SSL-Protected website.

Comment: Yes. That's it. But the problem was a CSS file with "http://". I just took out the http and left "//". Simpler than I thought. Thanks

Comment: In some way it was disturbing ckEditor... But, that's ok.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did to work around this:

I loaded a script over the unsecure http connection, which just sets a global variable. In the onload event i checked if the variable was set. If not, i show a warning.

Script to load over HTTP:

```
var unsecureContentLoaded = true;
```

Example code which checks if content was loaded (loaded over HTTPS):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(typeof unsecureContentLoaded === "undefined"){
        alert("unsafe content could not be loaded!");
    }
});
```